# PHP array stored in session is set to null if we initialise a array with same with same key, is it coding issue or php issue?

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

here is the code I am trying to execute, it was working fine on my localhost and another server PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11 but this creates problem in PHP Version 5.2.17 on a shared hosting

```
<?php
/* PHP version PHP Version 5.2.17   
 * Server API   CGI/FastCGI
 */
session_start();
$products = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $products = array("somedata1", "somedata2", "somedata3");
    $_SESSION['products'] = serialize($products);
    $_SESSION['test_products'] = serialize($products);
    echo "<br/>session products<br/>";
    print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['products']));
    echo "<br/>session test_products<br/>";
    print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['test_products']));
} else {
    echo "<br/>session products<br/>";
    print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['products']));
    echo "<br/>session test_products<br/>";
    print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['test_products']));
}
?>
```

On first run outputs

```
session products
Array ( [0] => somedata1 [1] => somedata2 [2] => somedata3 ) 
session test_products
Array ( [0] => somedata1 [1] => somedata2 [2] => somedata3 )
```

but on reloading

```
session products

Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/uaustral/public_html/itoi/test.php on line 17

session test_products
Array ( [0] => somedata1 [1] => somedata2 [2] => somedata3 )
```

Same code works fine on my PHP version PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11

Am I missing something (that is automatically corrected in new PHP version) or is it a PHP bug for the old version ?

Comment: Error or no error i think you should upgrade your current version of PHP

Comment: Please disable `register_globals`.

Comment: why do you serialize your arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with `register_globals` enabled, any array-item in `$_SESSION` is also known as a variable by that key:

With `register_globals` on:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($products);
```

Should show you the unserialized string. Because you later say `$products = array();` you are implicitly altering `$_SESSION['products']`. Solution: disable `register_globals`, and on a side note: you don't need to serialize that data, a session can hold multi-dimensional arrays just fine. Just make sure to have any needed class-definitions loaded before calling `session_start`, or have an autoload function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post to help you :

http://www.phphelp.com/forum/index.php?topic=11483.0

"It's working now...I did a comparison between the php.ini files on my machine and the production server. I turned off 'Register Globals' in the php.ini file on the production server and now the cart is working perfectly! Thanks"

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#105588.

the session_decode function even says that.